# Sheet View struct crashes due to "unresolved identifier" error

Tags: identifier, tasklist

## First Stack Overflow Question

I'm new to iOS Development. This is my second app in the class and I've followed along the tutorial and I cannot figure out what is wrong here.

I created a new SwiftUI file and named it "NewTaskView" and now I'm trying to use the struct "NewTaskView in a sheet view.
Why is Xcode saying "Use of unresolved identifier 'NewTaskView', when it has been created but in a separate SwiftUI file?

Here are my code snippets and a screenshot of the error

## NewTaskView.swift

```
    import SwiftUI

struct NewTaskView: View {
    @State var text = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Task Name", text: $text)
    }
}

struct NewTaskView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NewTaskView()
    }
}
```

## ContentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var taskStore: TaskStore
    @State var modalIsPresented = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(taskStore.tasks) { task in
                Text(task.name)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Tasks")
        .navigationBarItems(
                trailing:
            Button(action: {
                self.modalIsPresented = true
                
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
            }
        )
    }.sheet(isPresented: $modalIsPresented) {
            NewTaskView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(taskStore: TaskStore() )
    }
}
```

## Screenshot of Code with Error

[Use of unresolved identifier 'NewTaskView' error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9ygI.png)

Comment: Product -> Clean build folder then build again. This should work. Sometimes Swift UI takes time to register all views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

Bug in xcode 11.7 works fine in xcode 12